# Thread 1 signal SIGABRT can't load Main.Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, sigabrt

I don't know what I did, but I screwed up my app and now it crashes before it loads and I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 
'NSBundle </Users/MasonSatnick/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9F0F56D8-AA2C-459F-84A3-BB17F5982716/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A84FCDB3-1F61-486F-A108-863858F7AD76/Dodge The Box.app> 
(loaded)' with name 'Main''
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a storyboard called _Main.storyboard_?

Comment: @matt yes i do and it's always been named Main.Storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing's first. Quit Xcode but leave the simulator running. Tell the Simulator to Reset. Then clean out all the contents of the Derived Data folder and throw them away.

Now launch Xcode and see if the problem is miraculously fixed.

If not, check your *Info.plist*. It should have a "Main storyboard file base name" entry whose value is "Main". If it has transmuted to some other entry (e.g. a main *nib* file), fix it.

Comment: ummmm my info.plist may have gotten screwed up. I deleted it and made a new one, but I did it in a screwed up way. I revealed where the file was and it wasn't in the correct app folder, so I just moved it, and now it's red. When I launch the app now, it says into.plist couldn't be opened because there is no such file. ummmm.... what do I do now

Comment: I think I need a whole new info.plist, can you help me set it up because I have no idea what I'm doing

Comment: Just make a new project.

Answer (score 1):

With out being able to see your Project i'm going to shotgun some solutions that might be the issue.

1. Make sure that in your Target > General, you have selected the correct storyboardFile 
   [image: Main Interface needs to be set to Main]
2. Make sure your Main.storyboard is checked for the target you are using. In my case it's "The Rap App"

[image: checked]

3. If neither of these are the issue Right click on Main.Storyboard and click reveal in finder and make sure your find hasn't moved. If this is the case Main.Storyboard will most likely be Red.
4. Hold Shift + Option + Command + K and then press "Clean". Then Quit Xcode and Reopen.

If it is still giving you issues comment on this answer with and new information and i will try and help further.

EDIT:
Here are the steps to recreate an Info.Plist file.

1. Delete your current .plist file.
2. Type Command + N > iOS > Resources > Property List
3. VERY IMPORTANT name the file "Info" if you don't it won't work.
4. Right click on your new info.plist > open as... > Source Code.
5. highlight EVERYTHING and paste in the code below (Note: For further readers change "mason" to your company identifier)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
   <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
   <string>en</string>
   <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
   <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
   <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
   <string>com.mason.Dodge-The-Box</string>
   <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
   <string>6.0</string>
   <key>CFBundleName</key>
   <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
   <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
   <string>APPL</string>
   <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
   <string>1.0</string>
   <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
   <string>????</string>
   <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
   <string>1</string>
   <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
   <true/>
   <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
   <string>LaunchScreen</string>
   <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
   <string>Main</string>
   <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
   <array>
       <string>armv7</string>
   </array>
   <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
   <array>
       <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
       <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
       <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
   </array>
   <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
   <array>
       <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
       <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
       <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
       <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
   </array>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
6. Right click your info.plist file > View as... > Property List.
7. GO Target > build Settings > search for "info.plist file"
8. make sure the value is "My App Name/Info.plist"
9. Shift + Command + option + K > press "clean"
10. build and run!

Comment: all of that is correct, I think my info.plist got screwed up

Comment: Is there a reason you deleted you info.plist? or was it an accident? I can help if you want to get your old info.plist back or if you want to fix your new info.plist. Let me know which and ill post another answer

Comment: I think I lost my old one for good... could you help me make a new one? It'd be a HUGE help

Comment: In Xcode go File > Restore Snapshot...
DON'T PRESS RESTORE!!! We are just looking to see if you have any snapshots available. Comment Below yes or no.

Comment: Are you asking if I have the ability to click the Restore Snapshot button?

Comment: Nope, You can press "Restore Snapshots..." but NOT the button that pops up with the dialog that says "Restore..."

Comment: Darn. Ok it was worth a try. How many variable does your new info.plist have? If you created a new one from scratch it will just say "ROOT" if not it will have around 20 (give or take) with the firestone being "Information Property List". which do you have?

Comment: yea it just says root.... :/ now what I named it the same as my old info.plist so it's called `Dodge The Box-info.plist`

Comment: I will make you one and post it in my answer, but first what is your company identifier? com.*THIS*.MyAppName

Comment: com.mason.Dodge-The-Box

Comment: pasting it in is not working. I'm going out to dinner soon so I may not respond

Comment: Also make sure that you RIghtclicked your file > View as... > Source Code

Comment: Copying and pasting worked. I just have to work out a few errors with the target, but i had to leave for dinner, I'll try and fix it later and I'd it doesn't work I'll comment here again, unless there's another way i can contact you

Comment: You can delete it, sorry i haven't checked until now

Answer (score 0):

I had mine set to:

[image]

But I had to set it to:

[image]

Usually the value you need to select, is in the drop down. You just have to select it.